# Find all the points on circle

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A circle is given by the equation of the form $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$. Find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ with $c \ne 0$, such that the resulting circle has as many points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$ as possible. Find all the point on the circle, and give a brief justification as to why no other circle has more points in $\mathbb{Z}_7 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$.

my idea is that $a,b,x,y \in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}$ and $c \in {1,2,3,4,5,6}$

let $c \in {1,2,3,4,6}$ then $c^2$ not sum of two squares but for $c=5$, $c^2$ is sum of two squares so we get the most points is this logic correct. If not how do i solve this please. 
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your argument is not correct. For example, for $c=2$ we have that $c^2=4$ is the sum of two squares in many ways; for example $3^2+4^2=4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/7$. Or $0^2+2^2=4$, or $0^2+5^2=4$.

Comment: Actually squares are $0,1,2,4$ so that sums of squares are $1=1+0=4+4$, $2=1+1=0+2$, $3=1+2$, $4=2+2=0+4$, $5=1+4$, $6=2+4$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes i was just thinking the same way as well a minute ago but struggling to come with solution can you help with an answer or an approach thanks

Comment: Hint: write $\mathbb{Z}/7$ as $0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3$, so that squaring gives less cases. Furthermore, can we assume that $a=b=0$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde why can we assume $a,b=0$ , what's the reason that this gives the largest number of points?

Comment: There is a bijection between the circle of equation $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=c^2$$ and the circle $$x^2+y^2=c^2$$ simply shift every point of the first circle by $(-a,-b)$. Hence, it is enough to consider $a=b=0$.

Comment: @Crostul Thanks makes perfect sense i can now write up solution Thanks